# Javascript no longer a scripting language?

Tags: javascript, html, scripting, windows-runtime

I was baffled today when someone mentioned on a group that Javascript has evolved from the scripting language it was to a language that nearly equals Java - ie. It can also be used to develop native apps by combining it with html5/css anywhere. All the places which I can grab an understanding of Javascript online currently still describe it as a scripting language, and my understanding of the *scripting concept* is that you script for an application and the app interpretes. Given this, I have three questions:

1. Is Javascript still a scripting language?
2. Who really defines what the *standard Javascript* is?
3. Is there a need to redefine the javascript which is now evolving so much in app development?

I'll really appreciate official links/sources. Thanks.

Comment: What's your definition of "scripting language"?  (And where did that definition come from?)  As to who defines the language standard, [see this](http://goo.gl/yVlt).

Comment: Yes, it is still a scripting language because it's (typically) not pre-compiled to a binary.  Yes, you can create complex applications with scripting languages.  No, I would not want to create a complex app with JavaScript.

Comment: PHP & python are "scripting" languages too, as the Shakespeare opined "A rose by any other name would smell as sweet"... I think this Q belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ though...

Comment: @EricJ. Thanks, Exactly. I also wonder why the standard for Javascript is so loose. I previously thought the standard was defined by w3schools, but even now I'm still confused. ECMA does not mention Javascript in its home page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) Yes. It is at least a language that gets interpretated and not compiled (even tho, V8 does some on-the-fly assembly)

2.) [ECMA](http://www.ecma-international.org/)

3.) The language is on the flux all the time. Right now [ES.Next](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aspecification_drafts) (ES6 or "Harmony") is on the way.

Comment: thanks. w3schools though says that Javascript is derived from ECMAScript and ECMA does not even mention Javascript on their page. Also, I wonder if other companies can actually utilize Javascript for their own purpose and still maintain calling it the name Javascript. It seems like some sort of abuse.